# Travis CI - Using repository environment variables in .travis.yml

Tags: travis-ci

I'm looking to declare environment variables in my Travis CI repository settings and use them in my .travis.yml file to deploy an application and post a build notification in Slack.

I've set environment variables in my Travis CI repository settings like so:

[image: Travis CI repository environment variables]

My .travis.yml file appears as the following:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '0.12'
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
deploy:
  edge: true
  provider: cloudfoundry
  api: $CF_API
  username: $CF_USERNAME
  password: $CF_PASSWORD
  organization: $CF_ORGANIZATION
  space: $CF_SPACE
notifications:
  slack: $NOTIFICATIONS_SLACK
```

When I add the values into the .travis.yml file as they are, everything works as planned.

However, when I try to refer to the environment variables set in the repository, I receive no Slack notification on a build status, and the deployment fails.

Am I following this process correctly or is there something I'm overseeing?

Comment: What happen if you add `before_script: echo $CF_USERNAME` in your .travis.yml file? Is the content of the env variable printed in your build log?

Comment: That's correct, it's displaying the environment variable!

Comment: Should I be using `echo $ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it is probably too early in Travis CI's sequence for your environment variables to be read.

What I would suggest is to rather encrypt them using the `travis` [command-line tool](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb).

E.g.

```
$ travis encrypt
Reading from stdin, press Ctrl+D when done
username
Please add the following to your .travis.yml file:

secure: "TD955qR6qvpVIz3fLkGeeUhV76deeVRaLVYjW9YjV6Ob7wd+vPtACZ..."

Pro Tip: You can add it automatically by running with --add.
```

Then I would copy/paste the `secure: "TD955qR6qvpVIz3fLkGeeUhV76d..."` result at the appropriate place in your .travis.yml file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '0.12'
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
deploy:
  edge: true
  provider: cloudfoundry
  api:
    secure: "bHU4+ZDFeZcHpuE/WRpgMBcxr8l..."
  username:
    secure: "TD955qR6qvpVIz3fLkGeeUhV76d..."
```

You can have more details about how to encrypt sensitive data on Travis CI [here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I have to supply a value also?

Comment: You should do `travis encrypt` + `<enter>` in your repository's directory, then enter the value followed by `<Ctrl+D>`. This will output a value starting with `secure: ...`.